# JPA delete executes update query in the background

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to delete my JPA entity from the database using **JpaRepository.deleteById()**, but I am getting a weird error:

```
NULL not allowed for column "USER_ID"; SQL statement:
update event set from_date=?, name=?, user_id=?, until_date=? where id=? [23502-199]
```

As you can see, it executes an **UPDATE** query, but I don't know why.

My model looks like this

```java
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private User organizer;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date fromDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date untilDate;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "event_allowed_users",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "event_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    private List<User> allowedUsers;
}
```

```java
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String user;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String mail;

    private boolean active;
}
```

I also have my own SQL schema queries

```sql
create table user (id bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, active boolean not null, mail varchar(255) not null unique, user varchar(255), primary key (id));

create table event (id bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(255), from_date timestamp not null, until_date timestamp not null, user_id bigint not null, primary key (id));

alter table event add constraint fk_user_id1 foreign key (user_id) references user(id);

create table event_allowed_users (event_id bigint, user_id bigint, foreign key (event_id) references event(id) on delete cascade, foreign key (user_id) references user(id) on delete cascade);
```

Any idea where did I make the mistake ?

Comment: You cannot delete a user without deleting all related events first.

Comment: @MartinFrey Doesn't spring boot manage it automatically ? I thought `on delete cascade` does the trick.

Comment: Not on your organizer attribute.

Comment: @MartinFrey But I don't want to delete the user from the database. It is just a reference. What should I do ? I thought it is an issue with my ManyToMany relationship.

Comment: I removed the ManyToMany relation and it works, so the problem is in ManyToMany relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue, but not the **ORM** way.

I used **native query** to delete the event and it works like a charm. It deletes the event as well as ManyToMany relation table.

My service looks like this:

```java
@Resource
    private EventRepository eventRepository;

@Transactional
public void deleteEvent(Long id) {
    eventRepository.customDelete(id);
}
```

I had to add **@Transactional** since the DELETE operation needs to be executed in the transaction.

This is the repository native query:

```java
@Modifying
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM event WHERE id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    void customDelete(Long id);
```

When using INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, you need to use **@Modifying** for your query.